# PHPStorm v.5 issues

Tags: debugging, ide, phpstorm

I use PHPStorm 5.0.2 for debugging php/mysql projects with WAMP framework (php 5.3.1, Apache 2.2.9, mysql 5.5.24 on Windows 7 platform).

Question 1: Some times in a project, when watch debug variables are used, they take some seconds to refresh on the debug panel, after each code step. Each watch variable takes a few seconds to refresh, so the more watches have been defined, the more slowing down takes place during code stepping, rendering debugging disappointedly slow. So, for example, I cannot press 'Step over' every second, because I have to wait till watch values are refreshed, before I press the next 'Step over' and this may take 5 or more seconds.

This didn't use to happen before, it started happening lately and also it doesn't happen all the time. When it doesn't happen, the code stepping can advance very quickly, as it usually did.

In this project I have set up quite a few breakpoints, so I was wondering if they are the culprit. I tried to disable most of them (not delete them, since I need to keep them for future use), but I didn't see any improvement.

I also tried different xdebug versions, but no change took place.

I have also tried to switch browsers, delete browser data (cache, etc), restart WAMP server, browser, phpStorm, even Windows, but many times the issue remains. Other times, it disappears for a little while and it reappears later in the code.

I was wondering what reasons might produce this slow refresh.

Question 2: Is there any way to export or save breakpoints from a project?

Question 3: If I tried PHPStorm 7, in case this slow-refresh issue disappeared, could I open the PHPStorm 5 project in order to not loose the breakpoints I have already set?

Comment: **1)** PhpStorm v8 is about to be release in 2 months or so -- your v5 is too old and the issue could be fixed in current stable v7.1.3 (as you have stated yourself); **2)** No -- why this functionality would even be required? **3)** Yes -- it should preserve such info. In any case: just make backup of your project settings (`.idea` subfolder) before trying new version.

Comment: 1) Yes, that's the reason I wanted to try version 7, in case it is fixed, but I am not sure if this issue has been fixed.

2) I just wanted to make sure I don't have to create all the breakpoints from scratch.

3) Yes, I noticed that the 'workspace.xml' file has the breakpoints saved. I just didn't find anywhere in the phpstorm documentation about the possibility of opening an older version project (phpstorm version) from inside a later version.